# Invalid partitions table! after deleting fully encrypted ubuntu disk and install ubuntu over it

Tags: grub2, partitioning

I've had ubuntu installed as fully encrypted disk and decide to delete and install normally. After I did that, I got the `Invalid partitions table!` error and can't boot.

I have done this using live CD / Try ubuntu

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda print
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ACF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   49.6GB  49.1GB  ext4
 4      49.6GB  492GB   442GB
 3      492GB   500GB   8490MB  linux-swap(v1)

$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1497772032 bytes, 2925336 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4EDCF3CF-5ED8-46C9-817E-02A0CC36ED35

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1050624  96941248  95890625  45.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  960188416 976771071  16582656   7.9G Linux swap
/dev/sda4   96942080 960188415 863246336 411.6G Linux filesystem

Partition table entries are not in disk order.




Disk /dev/sdb: 15 GiB, 16108224512 bytes, 31461376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x15e2543d

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *        0 3035519 3035520  1.5G  0 Empty
/dev/sdb2       14432   19295    4864  2.4M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

I  have removed the /dev/ram15 and similar.

Before I reinstalled I got the warning that linux thinks block size is 512B and disk reports sometihng else. Also I notice it says `Partition table entries are not in disk order.` Is that a problem?

This laptop should also have a very small SSD drive which I didn't see in this output.

How to fix this?

Update: if I press F12 to select boot order and select entry `ubuntu` then it starts and works fine. I guess problem is in grub, uefi or something like that.

Comment: The "partition table entries are not in disk order" message is *not* a problem; ignore it. You might try using `gdisk` on the disk, and in particular its `v` option, which checks for partition table errors. Beyond that, please post a screen shot (digital photo) of the "invalid partition table" error; it's not clear to me what's producing that message (EFI, boot loader, Linux kernel, or conceivably something else), and the context of the message may help. Describing the sequence leading up to the message, and anything that happens after it appears, may also be helpful.

Comment: @RodSmith - it's just that message on completely blank black screen.  If I press F12 to select device to boot from and boot from something called `ubuntu` then it works. I guess I gotta fix grub or something, but I've failed for last 2 hours

Comment: Please provide the screen shot anyway. Subtle things like fonts can be important clues! Does the message appear before or after you are able to hit F12 to get to the firmware's boot manager? Also, please provide the output of `sudo efibootmgr -v` after you boot Ubuntu? (Edit your question to provide that output, and add four spaces to the start of each line of the `efibootmgr` output to preserve the formatting.)

Answer (score 0):

It was that BIOS was set in legacy mode. 
Setting it to EUFI - non secure boot fixed it.

I really don't know what changed it or why ubuntu hasn't detected it.